# .htaccess conditional .php removeal

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a basic redirect as follows. It works perfectly unless someone has `.php` in the url, then it breaks. Is there way to exclude somehow `.php` from this rule without it affecting the rest of the `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteRule ^folder1/(.*)$ /newFolder1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes sure you can do:

```
RewriteRule ^folder1/((?!.*?\.php$).*)$ /newFolder1/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```